# Difference of Gaussian in Edge detection

Tags: math, image-processing

Can anyone tell me how 2-D Gaussian function given as-

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/7/3/f7352f2a6fea01707e869432d39bfc21.png

where t is standard deviation.

1. How is it convoluted with Image(as in Difference of Gaussian)?
2. What is difference between Gaussian function and Gaussian filter?

Answer (score 3):

Based on that formula a filter mask is constructed as in (aka a discrete version of the gaussian function):

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm

This is for example a gaussian filter mask:

[image]

1).

This is how a convolution with the filter mask is done:

http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html

Basically the filter is flipped and then the filter moves over the image.
While moving over the image, the image pixel which corresponds to the middle of the mask gets the value of the weighted sum of the mask and the pixels. ( the link explains it better with an example)

2).

Gaussian function ==> continues

Gaussian filter ==> In this case, it is a discrete filter mask